# import cv2 error, libcudart.so.6.5 no such file

Tags: python, opencv, cuda

When invoked in python, cv2 is looking for the wrong libcudart.so. Here is the error after import cv2

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.6.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

I have both CUDA 6.5 and 7.5 installed on my system. But other apps seem to have no problem finding 7.5.

Here is my settings : ubuntu 14.04, OpenCV 3.0.0, python 2.7, cuda 6.5 and cuda 7.5

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH looks like

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/home/rspace/shogun-4.0.0/build-release/src/shogun:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

NOTE: the /usr/local/cuda is actually a link to /usr/local/cuda-7.5.

Comment: What is the full path to libcudart.so.6.5 on your system? It's likely that `/usr/local/cuda` is actually a symlink on your system that actually points to `/usr/local/cuda-7.5`, so the `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` entry in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't allow codes that are built against CUDA 6.5 to find the appropriate libraries. You could try adding the exact path to libcudart.so.6.5 to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Regarding the "wrong" libcudart.so, the application will "look for" whichever one it was built against (linked against). An app linked against CUDA 6.5 can't use the CUDA 7.5 libraries instead

Comment: full path : /usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64. And yes, /usr/local/cuda indeed points to cuda-7.5.

Comment: The OpenCV was just built rebuilt from source with cmake :                                  
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..

Comment: Notice it does *not* have the flag CUDA_GENERATION=Auto. I'm wondering if that might be needed.

Comment: add `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: hey it's getting more strange. I just looked into CMakeCache.txt, which is where the dependencies are specified. I see CUDA_VERSION:STRING=7.5. So why is it looking for 6.5?

Comment: You are confusing compiling the code with runtime behavior.  The error message "libcudart.so.6.5: cannot open shared object file:..." is arising at **runtime**, and it is the runtime linker that cannot find the file.  This is because at compile time, the code was linked against that file.  You fix the runtime linker problem by modifying your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, without trying to recompile anything.  If you are now asking how to rebuild OpenCV using CMake, that looks like a different question to me.  Why don't you try the suggestion I made about your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and re-run the python test?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, your suggestion works! Big thank. Then I realize something that explains why on earth cv2 is tied to cuda 6.5. The reason is : I actually have another opencv folder somewhere, which was built long ago, before I got cuda 7.5, and my 'PYTHONPATH' points to the /release/lib of this directory. So, whenever i start python and import, it's grabing stuff from this old dir.

Comment: @horaceT: please add a short answer summarising the solution you found to the problem

Answer (score 3):

To make the long story short, here is what happened.

I have two OpenCVs in my system. One was compiled and built on CUDA 6.5, but it was never `make install`ed. Before last week, I had `PYTHONPATH` set to the `.../release/lib` of this local folder, which is somewhere in my user home directory. At the same time, my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has a subpath `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, where `/usr/local/cuda` is actually a symlink pointing to CUDA 6.5.

Previously when I invoked `import cv2`, python knew where to look thanks to `PYTHONPATH` and opencv knew where to find CUDA thanks to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Last week I bought a new nvidia GPU; when installing it I upgraded CUDA to 7.5. In doing so, the symlink `/usr/local/cuda` was changed to point to cuda-7.5.

Thus, when invoking in python, cv2 was still going to the same symlink, but saw all the stuff associated with 7.5, and it was confused.

To make cv2 work again, all i have to do is to add the cuda 6.5 to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as suggested by Mr. Crovella. However, that doesn't solve my problem because I want to use the new opencv compiled on CUDA 7.5, but that belongs to a different thread...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved that problem by installing `opencv-python:

```
$pip install opencv-python
```

this instruction works for me